# Select blank and non-blank cells and give rowname

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a pipeline in R which is quite specific, but I hope someone can help me. I'll explain step by step what I want to achieve.
I have a dataset with 203 rows and 378 columns. I want to extract the column names from my dataset and divide them into new vectors based on whether the cell is blank or not.

I will give a fictive dataset (with less variables):

```
X1 <- c("group_1667", 4, "protein", 115, 116, NA, "GA002_48", "GA003_79", "GA004_10", NA, "GA006_3")
X2 <- c("group_453",3 , "protein", 52, 137, NA, NA, "GA003_88", NA, "GA005_32", "GA006_98")
dt <- data.frame(rbind(X1, X2))
colnames(dt) = c("Gene", "No.isolates", "Function", "Group Size", "QC", "GA001","GA002", "GA003","GA004","GA005","GA006")
```

From this dataset, I would like to obtain an output like this:

```
group_1667_pres   group_1667_abs   group_453_pres   group_453_abs
GA002             GA001            GA003            GA001  
GA003             GA005            GA005            GA002
GA004                              GA006            GA004
GA006
```

With 'pres' is a list of all non-blank cells and 'abs' is a list of all blank cells and this for each Gene. Based on this generated output, I want to link the GA numbers to a certain value from another dataset. This dataset looks as follows:

```
GAnumb    phenotype
GA001     2
GA002     4 
GA003     3
GA004     7
GA005     1
GA006     8
```

So I would obtain something like this:

```
group_1667_pres   group_1667_abs   group_453_pres   group_453_abs
4                 2                3                2  
3                 1                1                4
7                                  8                7
8
```

Basically, I want to extract data from one data frame based on the content of the cells (blank or not) of certain columns. Then I want to link this extracted data to a new data frame with values on which I want to perform t-tests. I have been trying to do so with dplyr but I am already stuck at the first steps (selecting blank cells and giving col names as output).

Comment: Your problem has many steps but you have to share first a reproducible example. The first chunk in your post is not reproducible because there are some objects that maybe have sense in your script, but not not for someone that is working outside (I am refering to objects `GA002_48`, `GA003_79`, `GA004_10`, etc.). So, please update your post first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I see that there are indeed some mistakes in my example. I've changed the GA objects to characters

Answer (score 0):

Data frame need to have the same number of rows in each column. I'd suggest keeping your result in a long format which will probably be easier to work with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

nice_result = dt %>%
  select(Gene, starts_with("GA")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Gene) %>%
  mutate(
    Gene = paste(Gene, ifelse(is.na(value), "abs", "pres"), sep = "_"),
    value = NULL
  ) %>%
  left_join(other_data, by = c("name" = "GAnumb"))
nice_result
#  # A tibble: 12 × 3
#  Gene            name  phenotype
#    <chr>           <chr>     <int>
#  1 group_1667_abs  GA001         2
#  2 group_1667_pres GA002         4
#  3 group_1667_pres GA003         3
#  4 group_1667_pres GA004         7
#  5 group_1667_abs  GA005         1
#  6 group_1667_pres GA006         8
#  7 group_453_abs   GA001         2
#  8 group_453_abs   GA002         4
#  9 group_453_pres  GA003         3
# 10 group_453_abs   GA004         7
# 11 group_453_pres  GA005         1
# 12 group_453_pres  GA006         8
```

If you really want output closer to your format, you could put each column in a `list`:

```
nice_result %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  group_split %>%
  lapply(\(x) data.frame(x$phenotype) %>% setNames(x$Gene[1]))
# [[1]]
#   group_1667_abs
# 1              2
# 2              1
# 
# [[2]]
#   group_1667_pres
# 1               4
# 2               3
# 3               7
# 4               8
# 
# [[3]]
#   group_453_abs
# 1             2
# 2             4
# 3             7
# 
# [[4]]
#   group_453_pres
# 1              3
# 2              1
# 3              8
```